# Oracle Case Failure Not An Object Or Ref

Tags: sql, oracle, gis

I'm getting the failure `ORA-22806: not an object or REF`
when querying

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN "SHAPE" IS NULL THEN NULL
              ELSE ("SHAPE").SDO_POINT.X END)
FROM (SELECT null AS "SHAPE" FROM DUAL)
```

in Oracle. It appears Oracle is evaluating the `else` statement even though the case expression is true. Anyone know a way to make this work? Requirements are to return null if "SHAPE" is null, otherwise return ("SHAPE").SDO_POINT.X. **Edit:** This also needs to be done without modifying the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle isn't evaluating the `ELSE` statement, but it seems it is checking the types of columns and expressions in your query.

I suspect that it starts type-checking your query by type-checking the subquery. The subquery is `SELECT null AS "SHAPE" FROM DUAL`. While type-checking this subquery Oracle doesn't know what the type the `SHAPE` column should be, so it chooses a type for it rather than make do without knowing the type for the time being and see if it can find out the real type later on.

For me (Oracle 18c XE), the error goes away if I cast `null` to `SDO_GEOMETRY`:

```
SQL> SELECT (CASE WHEN "SHAPE" IS NULL THEN NULL
  2                ELSE ("SHAPE").SDO_POINT.X END)
  3  FROM (SELECT CAST(null AS SDO_GEOMETRY) AS "SHAPE" FROM DUAL);

(CASEWHEN"SHAPE"ISNULLTHENNULLELSE("SHAPE").SDO_POINT.XEND)
-----------------------------------------------------------


SQL>
```

I am guessing that your database has a table with a `SHAPE` column of type `SDO_GEOMETRY`, but I could of course be wrong.

Comment: This works, but makes me realize I forgot to mention another requirement - I can't modify the subquery. Is there a way to return `null` or `("SHAPE").SDO_POINT.X` without modifying the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

> I forgot to mention another requirement - I can't modify the subquery

@SStrong: this additional requirement boils down to: "my unmodified code has a bug: how can I remove the bug without modifying my code?"

So all you can is put in an intermediary wrapper around the subquery which handles NULL values without applying case, using @lukewoodward suggestion. Something like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN "SHAPE" IS NULL THEN NULL
             ELSE ("SHAPE").SDO_POINT.X END)
FROM ( select case when "SHAPE" is null then cast(null as sdo_geometry) 
                   else "SHAPE" end as "SHAPE"               
        from  (SELECT null AS "SHAPE" FROM DUAL) --<-- your unmodifiable subquery
)
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `CASE` expression but that in the sub-query you are using `SELECT null FROM DUAL` and the `NULL` does not have a data type so Oracle assumes that it is `VARCHAR2` and then when it is passed to the outer query and you try to use `("SHAPE").SDO_POINT.X` it will raise the exception `ORA-22806: not an object or REF` because `SHAPE` is a `VARCHAR2` and is not an object or a `REF` so you cannot use the `.` syntax to extract member attributes from it.

What you can do is to use `CAST` in the outer query (and you do not need a `CASE` expression) to wrangle the `NULL` to a different data type:

```sql
SELECT (CAST(SHAPE AS SDO_GEOMETRY)).SDO_POINT.X AS x
FROM   (SELECT null AS "SHAPE" FROM DUAL)
```

---

However, that will not work if the inner sub-query can also return a non-`NULL` object and for that you can use some trickery with `UNION ALL` and `ROWNUM` to ensure the sub-query has the correct data type:

```sql
SELECT (SHAPE).SDO_POINT.X
FROM   (
  <your inner query> UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(NULL AS SDO_GEOMETRY) FROM DUAL
) s
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT (SHAPE).SDO_POINT.X
FROM   (
  SELECT null AS "SHAPE"            FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(NULL AS SDO_GEOMETRY) FROM DUAL
) s
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

Outputs `NULL` and:

```sql
SELECT (SHAPE).SDO_POINT.X
FROM   (
  SELECT SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(12,14,NULL), NULL, NULL) AS "SHAPE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(NULL AS SDO_GEOMETRY) FROM DUAL
) s
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

Outputs `12`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d9c96cc7d22891c03fd31f62eeea2e6)*